# need help in understanding if the way I am testing a function is correct

Tags: scala, mockito, playframework-2.6

I have written this function which is called when a user clicks a link. The function basically creates a copy of the user data with one field altered (thus keeping the original value unchanged i.e. not-mutable) and then updates the database with the new value

```
def confirmSignupforUser(user:User):Future[Option[User]] = {
    println("confirming user: "+user)
        val newInternalProfile = user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get.copy(confirmed=true)//new data which should be added in the database
        println("old internal profile: "+user.profile.internalProfileDetails.get)
        println("new internal profile: "+newInternalProfile)
        val newProfile = UserProfile(Some(newInternalProfile),user.profile.externalProfileDetails)
        println("old profile: "+user.profile)
        println("new profile: "+newProfile)
        val confirmedUser = user.copy(profile=newProfile)
        for(userOption <- userRepo.update(confirmedUser)) yield { //database operation
          println("returning modified user:"+userOption)
          userOption
      }
  }
```

To test the code, I have written the following spec

```
"confirmSignupforUser" should {
    "change confirmed status to True" in {
      val testEnv = new TestEnv(components.configuration)
      val externalProfile = testEnv.externalUserProfile
      val internalUnconfirmedProfile = InternalUserProfile(testEnv.loginInfo,1,false,None)
      val internalConfirmedProfile = internalUnconfirmedProfile.copy(confirmed=true)
      val unconfirmedProfile = UserProfile(Some(internalUnconfirmedProfile),externalProfile)
      val confirmedProfile = UserProfile(Some(internalConfirmedProfile),externalProfile)
      val origUser = User(testEnv.mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID(),unconfirmedProfile)
      val confirmedUser = origUser.copy(profile = confirmedProfile)
      //the argument passed to update is part of test. The function confirmSignupforUser should pass a confirmed profile
      when(testEnv.mockUserRepository.update(confirmedUser)).thenReturn(Future{Some(confirmedUser)})
      //// await is from play.api.test.FutureAwaits
      val updatedUserOption:Option[User] = await[Option[User]](testEnv.controller.confirmSignupforUser(origUser))
      println(s"received updated user option ${updatedUserOption}")
      updatedUserOption mustBe Some(confirmedUser)


    }
  }
```

I am not confident if I am testing the method correctly. The only way I can check that the `confirmed` field got changed is by looking at the return value of `confirmSignupforUser`. But I am actually mocking the value and I have already set the field `confirmed` to `true` in the mocked value (`when(testEnv.mockUserRepository.update(confirmedUser)).thenReturn(Future{Some(confirmedUser)})`.

I know the code works because in the above mock, the `update` method expects `confirmedUser` or in other words, a user with `confirmed` field set to `true`. So if my code wasn't working, `update` would have been called with `user` whose `confirmed` field was `false` and `mockito` would have failed.

Is this the right way to test the method or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to intialize `internalConfirmedProfile` in your test. The whole point is to start with `confirmed=false`, run the `confirmSignupforUser` method, and make sure that the output is `confirmed=true`.

You should check 2 things:

1. check that the return value has `confirmed=true` (which you do)
2. check that the repository has that user saved with `confirmed=true` (which you don't check). To check that you would need to load the user back from the repository at the end.

Comment: as I am mocking the database, I need to mock the return  value of `update` method. I need `internalConfirmedProfile` for that

Comment: This should be handled by the mockUserRepository, not by the test, i.e. your `mockUserRepository.update(o)` should update its private state with `o`. If you showed the code how your mockUserRepository is created, I would be able to advice something.

Comment: The easiest is to mock `update` method to return whatever is passed in like `mockUserRepository.update = x => future_with_result(Some(x))`, but this is not enough, because you should also check point (2).